# How do I get div ID selector working in HTML?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div id="nofries">
  <h1 class="restaurant mt-5 ms-3">CRAZY GREEKS</h1>
  <h3 class="ms-5">GREEK FOOD, SUBS &amp; PIZZA</h3>
</div>
```

This is my div ID, but my css isn't picking it up. I had it under class and that didn't work either. I even tried specifying it with "div.nofries" when it was a class; nothing. Any ideas?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    div#nofries {
        display: contents !important;
        text-shadow: -3px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

Also, does it matter that I'm using bootstrap? The way to use media queries in BS are too darn confusing for me so I prefer this way. Could it be interfering?

Comment: Are you test the changes on the correct resolution? (max width 900px)

Comment: Yes, I have inspect tools on and I change screen resolution constantly to check if changes have taken affect

Comment: The code in your question works perfectly (i.e. the text shadow shows up on a narrower viewport). Could you make it into an SO snippet and check that it shows your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
 
  <style>
   
.tblrow{
display: flex;
background:#ccc;
padding:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
 
  <style>
 @media  screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    div#nofries {
        display: contents !important;
        text-shadow: -3px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
        margin: auto;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nofries">
  <h1 class="restaurant mt-5 ms-3">CRAZY GREEKS</h1>
  <h3 class="ms-5">GREEK FOOD, SUBS &amp; PIZZA</h3>
</div>

</body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove only from media query      >      @media screen and (max-width: 900px)

Comment: Nope, doesn't even highlight the div when I move over it in the inspect tools

Comment: i will share you the code. it's working perfect

Comment: please check this it's working perfect

Comment: Margin auto is supposed to center the div and its contents correct? It's not doing so. Everything else is working as it should.

Answer (score -1):

Just try it with the declaration:

```
#nofries {
        display: contents !important;
        text-shadow: -3px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried that, that's why I was wanting to be more explicit with the `div` in front.